# GrapesJS - Posting the HTML as part of a form

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

As part of an editor for a page, I want to use GrapesJS as a WYSIWYG for the page content.

How can GrapesJS work inside of a form? On the same page you will be able to update the pages name, URL, etc.

When I save my form, I want the generated html from GrapesJS to be posted along side the name of the page, the URL, etc.

**Thoughts**

I've thought about having a hidden input and when there is a change made to content inside GrapesJS editor, it will update the value of the hidden input which will get posted when the form is saved but I'm not sure how to detect a change in grapesjs so I can update the inputs value.

Comment: It's nice to have thoughts, try to transform them into code and show us :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect changes like this:

```
editor.on('change:changesCount', e => {
     alert("Some changes were made");
});
```